# Weird Error When Extracting Numbers From String in C

Tags: c, string, runtime-error

I'm getting this weird error when trying to extract a 2 or 3 digits string of numbers, from a filename in C, some times it executes right, and sometimes it does not, the input filename is "EC2_122016_1676_corte22_03012017084106.TXT", and I only want the part that says "22" out of "corte22".

The correct result in this case should be "Code: 022", but, sometimes it shows another value, like "Code: 223" or "Code: 224", I don't have much experience with C and so, I can't get around to why this is happening, any help?

Here's the code I'm using to separate the filename from the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *sourceFileName = "EC2_122016_1676_corte22_03012017084106.TXT";
  char fileCode[4] = "\0";

  strcpy(fileCode, extractFileCode(sourceFileName));
  printf("Code: %s\n", fileCode);
}


char* extractFileCode(const char sourceFileName[]) {
    char *tmp = strdup(sourceFileName);
    strlwr(tmp);

    char *result = strstr(tmp, "corte");
    result = strtok(result, "_");
    result = extractNumbersFromString(result);

    char *t;

    // convert the number back to string, but add a leading zero
    sprintf(result, "%.3d", strtol(result, &t, 10));

    free(tmp);

    return result;
}

char* extractNumbersFromString(const char *source) {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(source) * sizeof(char));

    int index = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(source); i++) {
        if(isdigit(source[i])) {
            result[index++] = source[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: in `extractNumbersFromString` you're not nul-terminating `result` (and the buffer is too short)

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what do you mean when you say that the buff is too short? the end digit is never going to exceed 3 characters long.

Comment: yes, but `source` is 3 characters long _plus_ the null termination string that you need to store. So that's 4 characters or you're not able to print/parse it (`printf` or `strtol` expect a nul char to know when it's done, C strings work like that). Note that `strdup` allocates `strlen()+1` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `extractNumbersFromString` you're not nul-terminating `result` (and the buffer is too short), so another digit can slip at the end of the buffer.

Fix:

```
char* extractNumbersFromString(const char *source) {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);

    int index = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(source); i++) {
        if(isdigit(source[i])) {
            result[index++] = source[i];
        }
    }
    result[index] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

besides `* sizeof(char)` is useless since always 1.

Comment: I know about sizeof(char) being pointless, but I didn't want to put 1 in there, but I like your suggestion more. Thanks a lot

Comment: The funny thing is, that I had the result[index] = '\0'; at first, and I removed it for unknown reasons hehehe.

Comment: Its odd that `isalpha(some_char_that_may_have_a_negative_value)` is not well specified.  Suggest `isdigit((unsigned char) source[i])` .

Comment: @chux I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @AnubisLockward `char` may be a _signed_ `char` and so may have negative values. `isalpha()` is specified for all `unsigned char` and `EOF`, not necessarily for all `char`.  Characters are typically handled by the _unsigned_ values, so casting to `unsigned char` insures expected behavior.  This answer's `isdigit(source[i])` is undefined behavior, should `source[i]  < 0`.

Comment: Do I have to call "memset(result, '\0', sizeof(result));" right after the declaration "char *result = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);"?

Comment: nope, since you're filling it. Only the last zero matters.